# Preview image for IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have script which shows me image in django form before I click submit.

```
        function upload_img(input, id) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $(id).attr('src', e.target.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        };
```

But it does not work for IE 9. Can I make it work for this browser?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you tested the values of input.files, etc?

Comment: Nothing to do with Django, tags deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE 9 doesn't support `FileReader` but you can use [this](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/prototypes/fileapi/fileapi/info)

Comment: It requires new dll. It will be difficult to ask project users to upgrade theirs dll file. Is ther any way to do this without any installations?

Comment: maybe flash... but it's not the critical thing, so you beter not show image in IE if it is not supporting this feature.